# Corona not converting json to table

Tags: json, coronasdk

I am trying to convert the following json object to a table but Corona fails to do so and giving 0 for the print. I tried replacing "__type":"Object", with "" to prevent confusion but no luck.

```
   tempTable1 = '{"result":[{"__type":"Object","address":"95-97 Whitehorse Rd Blackburn VIC 3130","className":"allJobs","content":"Dr test","coord":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":-37.817272,"longitude":145.149913},"createdAt":"2015-05-21T05:15:45.012Z","done":false,"email":"na","job":"psychologist","objectId":"PfKJkmIQKw","order":1,"phone":"0422031410","postcode":"3130","suburb":"Blackburn VIC","updatedAt":"2015-05-27T08:15:46.607Z","web":"na"},{"__type":"Object","address":"Suite 9 10-12 Prospect St Box Hill ","className":"allJobs","content":"Dr 2)","coord":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":-37.817957,"longitude":145.118997},"createdAt":"2015-05-21T05:17:56.382Z","done":false,"email":"soboodi@yahoo.com","job":"lawyer","objectId":"xnLABEm5S4","order":1,"phone":"03 9890 0797","postcode":"3128","suburb":"Box Hill VIC","updatedAt":"2015-05-27T08:15:21.112Z","web":"na"}]}'


 local tables  = json.decode(tempTable1)
 print(#tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the results wrong way. Since it was creating a few tables inside other tables. The following gets them right.

```
print (event.response.result[5].email)
print (event.response.result[5].coord.latitude)
```